# Is there a polynomial which detects when the two smallest roots of a given real polynomial are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, field-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

The discriminant of a polynomial over a field is a "universal"* *polynomial function of its coefficients*, which is zero if and only if the polynomial has a multiple root in some field extension.

Now, let's limit the discussion to polynomials $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ with real coefficients, with all their roots real and non-negative.

> Is there a "universal"* polynomial in the coefficients of such $p(x)$, which is zero **if and only if** the **two smallest** roots of $p(x)$ are equal?

(equivalently, the smallest root of $p$ has multiplicity greater than $1$).

If not, is there such a universal real-analytic function of the coefficients?

---

*By "universal", I mean that the coefficients of the discriminant are independent of $p$.

Comment: If the two smallest roots are equal, doesn’t that make the multiplicity of the smallest root at least $2$?

Comment: Yes, but I asked for an "if and only if" condition.

Comment: Yes, but as stated you are saying it should be zero if and only if the multiplicity is one.

Comment: @MPW I suspect the OP omitted a $\gt$ symbol.

Comment: @MPW Yes, I omitted a "greater than". Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Ok, sorry, just trying to understand the question. Can you clarify? You’re looking for a function of the coefficients of $p$ which vanishes precisely when the smallest root of $p$ is a multiple root, right?

Comment: @MPW Yes, exactly. I am rather skeptic that such a thing exist, but I thought to ask anyway and see what happens...

Comment: A polynomial function on the coefficients of $p$ is a symmetric function of the roots of $p$ and so cannot distinguish roots.

Comment: @lhf Actually, I don't see a problem here: the fact the function is symmetric on the roots only means that it is in fact a function on the *unordered* tuple of the roots. But in such tuples we can distinguish between high multiplicity of the smallest number in the tuple and high multiplicity of other elements. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not for any degree of polynomials greater than $2$ (I will consider cubics but the general case is similar).  Indeed, suppose you had such a universal real-analytic function $q$ for cubics; we will write $q(p)$ for $q$ applied to the coefficients of a cubic $p$.  Let $f(t)=q((x-t)^2(x-1))$.  Then $f$ is real-analytic.  However, $f(t)=0$ for all $t\in(0,1]$ and $f(t)\neq 0$ for all $t>1$, which is not possible for a real-analytic function.

Comment: Why are you taking real analytic functions?

Comment: Because the question asked for them?

Comment: Ah I realize q is polynomial, and polynomials are neccesarily real analytic. Thanks